# Find 2 cells' values based on max value found in range

Tags: excel, vba, match

I have a multiplication style table with values inside x and y axis'. After the initial macro is run, I want to search for the max value, then find the corresponding x and y cells. Example...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5cqN.png)

In this example, the red text is the highest value, so it should find the 1 and the .015. But, there are some tables that might return multiple numbers, so I just want to pick the first cell found. Here is the full code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton6_Click()

Dim c As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim balanceValue As Range
Dim dayValue As Range
Dim multValue As Range
Dim lCol As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim whereRow As Long
Dim AddressOfMaxH As Variant
'Dim AddressOfMaxV As Range

'Set rng = Sheets("MacroTesting").Range("B91:CD110")
Set rng = Sheets("MacroTesting").Range("B91:C92")
Set balanceValue = Sheets("Header").Range("B4")
Set dayValue = Sheets("Header").Range("E17")
Set multValue = Sheets("Header").Range("F17")
getRow = Sheets("MacroTesting").Range("B91").Row
getCol = Sheets("MacroTesting").Range("B91").Column
whereRow = 90
lCol = Cells(whereRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

rng.Clear

For Each c In rng
    If ActiveCell.Column = lCol Then
        getRow = getRow + 1
        getCol = 2
    End If

    getRow = Sheets("MacroTesting").Cells(getRow, 1)
    dayValue = getRow

    getCol = Sheets("MacroTesting").Cells(whereRow, getCol)
    multValue = getCol

    c = balanceValue.Copy
    c.Select
    c = FormatCurrency(c, 0)
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    getCol = ActiveCell.Column + 1
    getRow = ActiveCell.Row
Next

With rng.FormatConditions.AddTop10
    .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
    .Rank = 1
    .Percent = False
    With .Font
       .Bold = True
       .ColorIndex = 3
    End With
End With

Set AddressOfMaxH = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0))
Set AddressOfMaxV = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0))
AddressOfMaxHoriz = Cells(whereRow, AddressOfMaxH.Column)
AddressOfMaxVerti = Cells(AddressOfMaxV.Row, 1)
dayValue = AddressOfMaxVerti
multValue = AddressOfMaxHoriz

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Here is the part where I'm trying to find the relevant cell.

```
Set AddressOfMaxH = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0))
Set AddressOfMaxV = rng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(WorksheetFunction.Max(rng), rng, 0))
AddressOfMaxHoriz = Cells(whereRow, AddressOfMaxH.Column)
AddressOfMaxVerti = Cells(AddressOfMaxV.Row, 1)
dayValue = AddressOfMaxVerti
multValue = AddressOfMaxHoriz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim rng As Range, f As Range

Set rng = Range("C6:G13")
Set f = rng.Find(Application.Max(rng), lookat:=xlWhole)

Debug.Print Cells(rng(1).Row - 1, f.Column).Value 'column header
Debug.Print Cells(f.Row, rng(1).Column - 1).Value 'row header
```

[image]